# C++, bool array not properly initialised

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

I am quite new to C++ so forgive me, if the mistake is stupid. I am currently working on a class, that can save single characters (only one of each) and do some simple operations.
The problem I am having seems to be in the constructor of the class. Since I only have characters I am using a bool array of the size 256. So if I wanted to add the character "A" to my array I would simply flip array[64] to 1.

To use the array in the way I want to I initialized it with zeros for every index. So it looks like this:

```
Set<char>::Set() {
  bool _elements[256] = {0};
}
```

If I check all the values of the member variable _elements now it does not only contain zeros. I don't know what might be causing this. There are no other function calls or anything in between.

```
Set set;
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) { printf("%d\n", set._elemens[i]; }
```

Comment: `bool _elements[256] = {0};` initialized only first value. If you want to initialize all array you have to user either `memset` C function of iterate and set to 0

Comment: @fnc12 err no, all are set to zero (`false` specifically in this case)

Answer (score 4):

You're initializing a local variable `_elements` inside the constructor, it will be destroyed when get out of the constructor, and has nothing to do with the member variable `_elemens`. (And note the name is not same.)

You can initialize the member variable by [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list):

```
Set<char>::Set() : _elemens {0} {}
```

or [in-class brace-or-equal initializer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) (I don't know how `Set` is declared so just as an example):

```
struct Set {
    bool _elemens[256] = {0};
};
```

And as @M.M pointed, for both cases just `{}` would work well (all of the elements will be set to `false`) and be preferable for your case.

Answer (score 1):

The array `_elements` is a local variable to Set() constructor. You're not supposed to be able to access it outside the Set() constructor.

The way you want to use it, you need the `_elements` to be a public member variable to class Set.